# IE8 Background filter doesn't work

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have a background-size: cover but it doesn't work in IE8 so I googled and found this

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='background.png', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='background.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

So I copied it into my script but it doesn't work, my script:

```
background: url('background.png') center top no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
max-height: 682px;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='background.png', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='background.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Comment: are those paths correct?

Comment: IE8 does not support multiple backgrounds natively.
You might try a polyfill http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/

Comment: I changed it Mike, but the path is correct yes.

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", you mean: 1) background is not displayed at all 2) background doesn't behave like "cover" or... I am asking, because I tested your snippet and it's working for me just fine.

Comment: He doesn't show anything, it's just a white screen

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. I take another div in which you want to give background.

```
<div class="your_class">
    <div class='mybg'></div>
</div>
```

and set style like this

```
.mybg
{
position:absolute; 
width:100%; 
height:100%;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='your_image_path',sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='your_image_path', sizingMethod='scale');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with using jQuery to resolve this, then [jQThumb](https://github.com/pakcheong/jqthumb) might help. This plugin was built to resolve background-cover issue in IE6, IE7 and IE8.